# Dynamic Dropdown List PHP AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

With instructions I found online, I created a very basic dynamic dropdown list (cascading dropdown) that looks at database values, and where the 2nd field (city) is populated based on what is selected in the first field (country). Below is my code I am using. I can get the first dropdown to populate with database data, however when I make a selection in the country field, nothing populates in the city field.  I'm thinking it ay have something to do with where I have my jquery (.js) file saved to. I have it saved in my index folder (localhost/cascadingdropdown/) but in the CascadingDropDown script it's referenced as  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js">. Thanks in advance!

**CascadingDropDown PHP script:**

```
<?php

include('connect2-mysql.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cascading Dropdown</title>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
type="text/css">
   .country, .city{
       margin: 20px
   text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="country">
<label>Country</label>
  <select name="country" onchange="getId(this.value);">
       <option value="">Select Country</option>
       //populate value using php
       <?php
       $query = "SELECT * FROM country";
       $results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
       //loop
       foreach ($results as $country) {

       ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["countryname"]; ?></option>
       <?php 
       }


       ?>
    </select>
</div>
<br></br>
<div class="city">
<label>City</label>
  <select name="city" id="cityList">
       <option value=""></option>

    </select>
</div>
<script> src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script>
   function getId(val){
        //we create ajax function
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "getdata.php",
             data: "id="+val,
             success: function(data){
                 $("#cityList").html(data);
             }

        });
   }

</script>
</body>
```

**Getdata.php script:**

```
<?php

include('connect2-mysql.php');

if(!empty($_POST["id"})) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE cid = $cid";
    $results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
    foreach ($results as $city) {
    ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $city["cityid"] ?>"><?php echo $city["cityname"]; ?></option>
   <?php


    }

}

?>
```

[image: File Location]
[image: element inspector console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing for `$_POST['id']` but not attributing it to anything.

Alter your code a little:

```
if(!empty($_POST["id"})) {
    $cid = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE cid = $cid";
    $results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
```

Comment: @ThioriumBR  I made the change as sugguested, however the 2nd dropdown is still not being populated from the first selection...

Comment: You can use Element Inspector on Firefox or Chrome to see the network traffic and see if your code is returning valid HTML. It will show you any errors on the console too.

Comment: @ThioriumBR I added image (see above) of error in Chrome element inspector console. Do you know what they refer to?

Comment: The errors in the element inspector are referring to these two lines of code: Line 37: `<script> src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>`    Line 41: `$.ajax({`

Comment: Your `<script>` tag is wrong. You are closing the tag before adding the `src` parameter.

Comment: I chnged it to this but it still isn't working: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"</script>`

Comment: Slightly different question, but would it be fairly easy to sort the dropdown values alphabetically? I tried altering the Country dropdown to be `<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY country";
    $results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
    //loop
    foreach ($results as $country) {
     
        
    ?>`    however when I do this and refresh the page it doesnt display any values at all.   I would like to do the same for the City dropdown.